# learn python the hard way exercise 14 not running in command prompt/powershell

Tags: python, windows

I'm doing learn python the hard way and exercise 14 makes me make a script which prompts the user a few different questions and for whatever reason whenever I try and execute the script (normally by typing in "python ex14 username" in cmpt) 
Here is the code for it

```
from sys import argv 

script, user_name = argv 
prompt = '>' 

print " Hi %s, I'm the %s script. " % (user_name,script) 
print "I'd like to ask you a few questions ." 
print "Do you like me %s?" % user_name 
lives = raw_input(prompt) 

print "where do you live %s?" % user_name 
lives = raw_input(prompt)  

print "What kind of computer do you have?" 
computer = raw_input(prompt)                                  

print """
Right, so you said %r about liking me. 
You live in %r. Not sure where that is 
And you have a %r computer. Nice. 
""" % (likes, lives, computer)
```

Also I'm using Windows 7 and Notepad++

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Whats the question?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the script itself, except your first `raw_input` variable is 'lives' when it should be 'likes'.

It seems to me that if you're trying to run the script by typing `python ex14 username` then the problem is most likely simply that you forgot to type in the .py extension. Just type in `python ex14.py username` and make sure you are in the directory your python scripts are stored in, then you should be all good.

If that isn't the problem then you should type out the exact error message you're receiving so people can be of more help. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

its working fine, you just mistyped in line #9, it should be 'likes' not 'lives'

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

E:\>python ex14.py yanuar
 Hi yanuar, I'm the ex14.py script.
I'd like to ask you a few questions .
Do you like me yanuar?
>yes
where do you live yanuar?
>ina
What kind of computer do you have?
>vaio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex14.py", line 21, in <module>
    """% (likes, lives, computer)
NameError: name 'likes' is not defined
```

the final script is to print all variable, and its expecting "likes" var.

```
E:\>python ex14.py yanuar
 Hi yanuar, I'm the ex14.py script.
I'd like to ask you a few questions .
Do you like me yanuar?
>Yes
where do you live yanuar?
>INA
What kind of computer do you have?
>Vaio

Right, so you said 'Yes' about liking me.
You live in 'INA'. Not sure where that is
And you have a 'Vaio' computer. Nice.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but even after I fixed line 9 it now says "File ":C\Users\George\ex14.py", line 1 from sys import argv Indentation error:unexpected indent

Comment: @DeuceKaboose, please remove all tabs/spaces(indent), refer to "^" mark in error message for location